# R-Shiny renders wrong results in a DataTable

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I programmed an app in shiny, but the calculated results are totally wrong :(.

I have got a data.frame:

```
          Label V1      V2
1 Begeisterung    6      3
2        Basis    2      4
3     Leistung    5      4
4  Indifferent    4      6
5      Reverse    0      0
6  Fragwuerdig    1      1
```

I have to calculate a score for "V1 and "V2". This is done with the following code:

```
CS_Minus1 <- (Ergebnis[2,2] + Ergebnis[3,2]) / ((-1)*(Ergebnis[1,2] + Ergebnis[2,2] + Ergebnis[3,2] + Ergebnis[4,2]))
CS_Minus2 <- (Ergebnis[2,3] + Ergebnis[3,3]) / ((-1)*(Ergebnis[1,3] + Ergebnis[2,3] + Ergebnis[3,3] + Ergebnis[4,3]))
```

Results are:
-0.4117647
-0.4705882

When i calculate this in normal R, absolutely works fine. In shiny i only receive 
-0.4117647
0

I have absolutely no clue, why the results in shiny differ.

**EDIT:** Shiny Code

```
output$tb <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(datensatz())){
      return ()
    } else
      tabsetPanel(tabPanel("About file", tableOutput("filedf")),tabPanel("CS Koeffizienten", DT::dataTableOutput("table")), 
                  tabPanel("Faktoren", DT::dataTableOutput("table2")), tabPanel("Plot", highchartOutput("table3")), tabPanel("Interpretation", htmlOutput("interpret")))
  })
})
```

If i use this code, i get wrong values.

```
      output$tb <- renderUI({
      tabsetPanel(tabPanel("About file", tableOutput("filedf")),tabPanel("CS Koeffizienten", DT::dataTableOutput("table")), 
                  tabPanel("Faktoren", DT::dataTableOutput("table2")), tabPanel("Plot", highchartOutput("table3")), tabPanel("Interpretation", htmlOutput("interpret")))
  })
})
```

If i just render my UI without a condition everything works fine and i can see all the correct val. I don´t understand why, for me that makes no sence. Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: you need to provided your shiny code

Comment: add enough code for others to understand the question and post the solution or remove the question

Comment: Your shiny code is not complete. Could You please explain what part of `output` in shiny shows the wrong values(is it `filedf`, `table2`, or??) and what are other outputs for?do You wanna display this two results called `CS_Minus1` and `CS_Minus2` as a table? what is `datensatz()`??